# Different Division behaviour inside and outside function?

Tags: python-2.7

I  was working on a function and there is something fishy going on.
Can someone explain this weirdness? For your convenience, here are the args you might need:

```
var1,var2,df1,df2,n1,n2 = .05, .08, 149, 164, 150, 165

num = float(var1/float(n1) + var2/float(n2))**2

den=float((var1**2/float(n1**2 * df1)) + (var2**2/float(n2**2 * df2)))

num/den
Out[44]: 307.19879975167265
num
Out[48]: 6.694214876033057e-07
den
Out[49]: 2.1791149188878324e-09

df_two_sampled_welch(.05, .08, 150, 165)
6.69421487603e-07
2.18790880087e-09
Out[50]: 305.9640727875991
```

Here is the above function:

```
def df_two_sampled_welch(var1, var2, n1, n2):
    df1, df2 = n1-1, n2-2
    num = float(var1/float(n1) + var2/float(n2))**2
    den = float((var1**2/float(n1**2 * df1)) + (var2**2/float(n2**2 * df2)))
    print num
    print den
    return num/den
```

Why is den inside not equal den outside??

Please don't tell me

```
__future__ import division
```

will solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also `print` the variables `num`, `den` you'll see that they are not different. The python console just uses different number format to show the values of the variables.

But the difference in `num/dev` comes from the fact that inside the function you change the values of `df1`, `df2`.

Comment `df1, df2 = n1-1, n2-2` and you'll get the same result or use the following:

```
df1, df2 = n1-1, n2-1
```

Comment: No. inside function variables have nothing to do with the variables declared outside. you can just use those arg values and paste them(note there is no df1 df2 as args for the func);
Try pasting the function in a new console and trying it out.
and just try using those steps w/o a function in both case, paste num/den within the function and outside returns two different values.
In particular **den** is diff.

Comment: I didn't say that they have something to do. But inside the function you use different values for `df1`,  `df2`, hence the difference in the division. For example inside function `df2==163` and not 164 as outside. This is because you subtract 2 and not 1.

Comment: Ohhhh S**tiest silly mistakes. thanks for reframing and pointing it out!